SVG Responsive Angular
I am Developing an Web app for a client and we both are getting frustated due to the SVG.
Basically we are creating an flowchart for every proccess the company has. They asked us to follow an already pre-made interface. Since we couldn't find any library for creating flows like they asked, we created everything from scratch and it was crazy, but in the end the SVG responsivity is 'breaking' the intire website.

As you can see, the flow continues to the right, but the page is cutting it of (literally), even with the scroll bar.

Basically we created all flows in separate files and we import all files in a different page, so we are creating child.
Our Code
 <div class="scroll">
  <svg cdkDrag width="100%" height="350px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <polyline points="100,10 350,10 350,10 1800,10 1800,320 55,320 55,10 100,10"
      style="fill: none; stroke: #c7c7c7; stroke-width: 1" />

    <!--Preparação de forno -->
    <rect x="100" y="70" rx="10" ry="10" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: preparacaoFornoPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: preparacaoFornoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="230" y1="106" x2="273" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="278,106 273,104 273,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="230" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: preparacaoFornoPercentage <= 95,
        verde: preparacaoFornoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="218" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: preparacaoFornoPercentage === 100 }"
      font-family="Arial" fill="#000">
      {{
      preparacaoFornoPercentage != "NA"
      ? preparacaoFornoPercentage + "%"
      : "NA"
      }}
    </text>

    <text x="120" y="102" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Preparação de
    </text>
    <text x="148" y="118" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Forno
    </text>

    <!-- Carga -->
    <rect x="280" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: cargaPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: cargaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="410" y1="106" x2="453" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="458,106 453,104 453,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="410" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: cargaPercentage <= 95,
        verde: cargaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="398" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: cargaPercentage === 100 }" font-family="Arial"
      fill="#000">
      {{ cargaPercentage != "NA" ? cargaPercentage + "%" : "NA" }}
    </text>

    <text x="327" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Carga
    </text>

    <!-- Carbonização -->
    <rect x="460" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: carbonizacaoPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: carbonizacaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="590" y1="106" x2="633" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="638,106 633,104 633,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="590" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: carbonizacaoPercentage <= 95,
        verde: carbonizacaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="578" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: carbonizacaoPercentage === 100 }"
      font-family="Arial" fill="#000">
      {{ carbonizacaoPercentage != "NA" ? carbonizacaoPercentage + "%" : "NA" }}
    </text>

    <text x="483" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Carbonização
    </text>

    <!-- Dia chuvoso -->
    <polygon points="840,106 740,58 640,106 740,153  " fill="rgb(230,230,230)" style="stroke-width: 2" />

    <text x="728" y="102" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Dia
    </text>
    <text x="714" y="118" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Chuvoso
    </text>

    <polyline points="740,153 740,165" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <text x="727" y="178" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Sim
    </text>
    <polyline points="740,185 740,197" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="740,202 738,197 742,197" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <polyline points="840,106 850,106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <text x="854" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Não
    </text>
    <polyline points="884,106 895,106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="900,106 895,104 895,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <!-- Cobertura do carvão -->
    <rect x="678" y="205" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" stroke-width="2" />

    <text x="702" y="236" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Cobertura de
    </text>
    <text x="721" y="252" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      carvão
    </text>

    <polyline points="808,240 967,240 967,140" fill="none" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="967,142 965,147 969,147" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <!-- Remontagem -->
    <rect x="902" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1032" y1="106" x2="1075" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1080,106 1075,104 1075,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <text x="925" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Remontagem
    </text>

    <!-- Coleta -->
    <rect x="1082" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: coletaPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: coletaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1212" y1="106" x2="1255" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1260,106 1255,104 1255,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="1210" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: coletaPercentage <= 95,
        verde: coletaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="1198" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: coletaPercentage === 100 }" font-family="Arial"
      fill="#000">
      {{ coletaPercentage != "NA" ? coletaPercentage + "%" : "NA" }}
    </text>

    <text x="1127" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Coleta
    </text>

    <!-- Análise Laboratorial -->
    <rect x="1262" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1392" y1="106" x2="1435" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1440,106 1435,104 1435,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />



    <text x="1303" y="102" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Análise
    </text>
    <text x="1290" y="118" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Laboratorial
    </text>

    <!-- Expedição -->
    <rect x="1442" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: expedicaoPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: expedicaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1572" y1="106" x2="1615" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1620,106 1615,104 1615,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="1570" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: expedicaoPercentage <= 95,
        verde: expedicaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="1558" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: expedicaoPercentage === 100 }"
      font-family="Arial" fill="#000">
      {{ expedicaoPercentage != "NA" ? expedicaoPercentage + "%" : "NA" }}
    </text>

    <text x="1475" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Expedição
    </text>

    <!-- Usina -->
    <rect x="1622" y="70" rx="100" ry="100" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white"
      stroke-width="2" />

    <text x="1667" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Usina
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>

and our scss from the child document:
   :host {

    .scroll{
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        cursor: pointer;

        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
        }
    
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
    
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #3b0261;
            border-radius: 2px;
            
        }

        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
            background-color: #78409c;
        } 

    }
    svg {
        width:150%;
        height: 150%;
        max-width: 150%;
        background-color: white;

        &:hover {
            cursor: grab;
        }

        text{
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .porcentagem{
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .cemPorcento{
            transform: translateX(-3px);
        }

        .titulo{
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .verificacao{
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .verde{
            stroke: rgb(143,208,78);
        }

        .verdePreencher{
            fill: rgb(143,208,78);
        }

        .vermelho{
            stroke: rgb(241,71,38);
        }

        .vermelhoPreencher{
            fill: rgb(241,71,38);
        }
    }
}    

and in our parent page we are importing and using p-tab from prime ng to display all the flows in tabs:
<body>
<div class="container">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <div class="flows">
        <h1 class="regiao-name">{{regiaoNome}}</h1>
        <div class="flow">

            <p-tabView>
                <p-tabPanel header="Viveiro Regional">
                    <a class="detalhamento"
                        href="/detalhamento/macros-processos/{{excelDataTime}}/{{Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.viveiro}}?query=!E2:L63&indexValues=5e6e7&name=Viveiro%20Regional">Ver
                        Detalhamento<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <app-viveiro-regional class="viveiro"
                        [jardimPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.viveiro,'!C3') | async"
                        [estaqueamentoPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.viveiro,'!C5') |async"></app-viveiro-regional>

                </p-tabPanel>
            </p-tabView>



        </div>

        <p-tabView>
            <p-tabPanel header="Silvicultura Regional">
                <a class="detalhamento"
                    href="/detalhamento/macros-processos/{{excelDataTime}}/{{Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.silvicultura}}?query=!F2:N70&indexValues=6e7e8&name=Silvicultura%20Regional">Ver
                    Detalhamento<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-silvicultura-regional-flow></app-silvicultura-regional-flow>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>

            <p-tabPanel header="Silvicultura 1ª Rotação">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-silvicultura-regional-flow></app-silvicultura-regional-flow>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>

            <p-tabPanel header="Silvicultura 2ª Rotação">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-silvicultura-segunda-rotacao></app-silvicultura-segunda-rotacao>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>

            <p-tabPanel header="Preparação de mudas">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-preparacao-de-mudas [alturaPercentage]="2"
                            [diametroPercentage]="90"></app-preparacao-de-mudas>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
        </p-tabView>


        <p-tabView>
            <p-tabPanel header="Colheita Regional">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-colheita-regional
                            [derrubadaPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.colheita,'!D2')|async"
                            [baldeioPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.colheita,'!D3')|async"
                            [tracamentoPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.colheita,'!D4')|async"
                            [transportePercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.regional.colheita,'!D5')|async"></app-colheita-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel header="Colheita Chácara">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-colheita-regional></app-colheita-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel header="Colheita Cruz Grande">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-colheita-regional></app-colheita-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel header="Colheita São Bento">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-colheita-regional></app-colheita-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
        </p-tabView>

        <p-tabView>
            <p-tabPanel header="Carvão Regional">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-carvao-regional
                            [preparacaoFornoPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.itamarandiba.carvao,'!D6')|async"
                            [cargaPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.itamarandiba.carvao,'!D2')|async"
                            [carbonizacaoPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.itamarandiba.carvao,'!D3')|async"
                            [coletaPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.itamarandiba.carvao,'!D8')|async"
                            [analiseLaboratorialPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.itamarandiba.carvao,'!D7')|async"
                            [expedicaoPercentage]="Spreadsheets.getExcelData(Spreadsheets.spreadsheetsId.itamarandiba.carvao,'!D9')|async"></app-carvao-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel header="Carvão Chácara">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-carvao-regional></app-carvao-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel header="Carvão Cruz Grande">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-carvao-regional></app-carvao-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel header="Carvão São Bento">
                <div class="flows">
                    <div class="flow">
                        <app-carvao-regional></app-carvao-regional>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
        </p-tabView>
    </div>

</div>

I really need help to put it responsive so the client stop making me go crazy.Basically this is how they want it:


The width and height of the SVG is 100% -- 100% of what? Instead of setting width and height, try to use the viewBox attribute on the SVG element.

Instead of "100%" try to calculate the width required to display all contents.

Just a note that the @angular-devkit/build-angular:application builder now supports svg imports

If you replace the width and height attributes on the svg element with a viewBox attribute (something like viewBox="0 0 1845 320", calculated from the size of the first polygon that makes up the border) the SVG will take up 100% of the width of the parent container. Now, the content of the SVG will not overflow.
If you need it to be more responsive you can style the SVG just as you would do this other images.


<svg cdkDrag viewBox="0 0 1845 320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <polyline points="100,10 350,10 350,10 1800,10 1800,320 55,320 55,10 100,10"
      style="fill: none; stroke: #c7c7c7; stroke-width: 1" />

    <!--Preparação de forno -->
    <rect x="100" y="70" rx="10" ry="10" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: preparacaoFornoPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: preparacaoFornoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="230" y1="106" x2="273" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="278,106 273,104 273,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="230" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: preparacaoFornoPercentage <= 95,
        verde: preparacaoFornoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="218" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: preparacaoFornoPercentage === 100 }"
      font-family="Arial" fill="#000">test</text>

    <text x="120" y="102" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Preparação de
    </text>
    <text x="148" y="118" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Forno
    </text>

    <!-- Carga -->
    <rect x="280" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: cargaPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: cargaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="410" y1="106" x2="453" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="458,106 453,104 453,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="410" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: cargaPercentage <= 95,
        verde: cargaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="398" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: cargaPercentage === 100 }" font-family="Arial"
      fill="#000">test</text>

    <text x="327" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Carga
    </text>

    <!-- Carbonização -->
    <rect x="460" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: carbonizacaoPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: carbonizacaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="590" y1="106" x2="633" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="638,106 633,104 633,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="590" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: carbonizacaoPercentage <= 95,
        verde: carbonizacaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="578" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: carbonizacaoPercentage === 100 }"
      font-family="Arial" fill="#000">test</text>

    <text x="483" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Carbonização
    </text>

    <!-- Dia chuvoso -->
    <polygon points="840,106 740,58 640,106 740,153  " fill="rgb(230,230,230)" style="stroke-width: 2" />

    <text x="728" y="102" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Dia
    </text>
    <text x="714" y="118" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Chuvoso
    </text>

    <polyline points="740,153 740,165" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <text x="727" y="178" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Sim
    </text>
    <polyline points="740,185 740,197" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="740,202 738,197 742,197" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <polyline points="840,106 850,106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <text x="854" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Não
    </text>
    <polyline points="884,106 895,106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="900,106 895,104 895,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <!-- Cobertura do carvão -->
    <rect x="678" y="205" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" stroke-width="2" />

    <text x="702" y="236" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Cobertura de
    </text>
    <text x="721" y="252" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      carvão
    </text>

    <polyline points="808,240 967,240 967,140" fill="none" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="967,142 965,147 969,147" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <!-- Remontagem -->
    <rect x="902" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1032" y1="106" x2="1075" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1080,106 1075,104 1075,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <text x="925" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Remontagem
    </text>

    <!-- Coleta -->
    <rect x="1082" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: coletaPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: coletaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1212" y1="106" x2="1255" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1260,106 1255,104 1255,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="1210" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: coletaPercentage <= 95,
        verde: coletaPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="1198" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: coletaPercentage === 100 }" font-family="Arial"
      fill="#000">
      test
    </text>

    <text x="1127" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Coleta
    </text>

    <!-- Análise Laboratorial -->
    <rect x="1262" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1392" y1="106" x2="1435" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1440,106 1435,104 1435,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />



    <text x="1303" y="102" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Análise
    </text>
    <text x="1290" y="118" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Laboratorial
    </text>

    <!-- Expedição -->
    <rect x="1442" y="70" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelhoPreencher: expedicaoPercentage <= 95,
        verdePreencher: expedicaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke-width="2" />

    <line x1="1572" y1="106" x2="1615" y2="106" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1" />
    <polygon points="1620,106 1615,104 1615,108" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2" />

    <circle cx="1570" cy="70" r="15" fill="white" [ngClass]="{
        vermelho: expedicaoPercentage <= 95,
        verde: expedicaoPercentage > 95
      }" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
    <text class="porcentagem" x="1558" y="75" [ngClass]="{ cemPorcento: expedicaoPercentage === 100 }"
      font-family="Arial" fill="#000">
      test
    </text>

    <text x="1475" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Expedição
    </text>

    <!-- Usina -->
    <rect x="1622" y="70" rx="100" ry="100" width="130" height="70" fill="rgb(230,230,230)" stroke="#white"
      stroke-width="2" />

    <text x="1667" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" fill="#000">
      Usina
    </text>
  </svg>



